# setup.py command to show install_requires?

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the list of packages specified in the `install_requires` parameter to the setup command (in setup.py)?

I'm looking for something similar to `pip show pkgname | grep -i requires`, but for local packages (and that reports version specifiers and filters).

The real task I'm solving is to check if versions specified in setup.py and requirements.txt have diverged, so if there is a tool that can do this directly...?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean my "diverged"?  setup.py and requirements.txt are for quite different tasks, setup.py has only the direct dependencies (possible with bounds for constraints) whereas requirements.txt has all the transitive dependencies too, and pinned to exact versions.

Comment: @wim e.g. when we've found that we need a specific version on older pythons, we would put `"attrs==21.4.0 ; python_version < '3.9'", "attrs>=22 ; python_version >= '3.9'"` in the setup.py file, mirroring the requirements.txt file.  If a new version is released that works universally it would be best to keep the setup.py file in sync with requirements.txt (which is used in CI).

Comment: There is no `setup.py` command for this as far as I know, and setuptools [no longer wants to be in the business of providing a command line interface](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html), so it won't ever happen. Maybe [`importlib.metadata.requires`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-requirements) can help? However, it does require the package to be installed (there are some hackarounds to trick it into thinking a package is installed if you need)

Comment: By the way, I don't think one should ever _pin_ in setup.py ever conditional for older Python versions. That's over-constraining the metadata, and as soon as something else in the dependency tree tries to constrain attrs suddenly you have a conflict and the package can't be installed at all. You can specifically exclude known broken versions using `!=` instead.

Comment: importlib.metadata.requires is perfect, I see your point about pinning in setup.py also. Thanks for all your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *installed* packages, use stdlib [`importlib.metadata.requires`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-requirements). Python 3.8+ is required, but there is a backport [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) for older Python versions. This is the easy case, because installed packages have already generated the metadata (including dependency specs) at installation time. For local source trees which aren't necessarily installed, read on.

There is a way to do this in Python APIs via distutils (which setuptools wraps):

```
import distutils.core
dist = distutils.core.run_setup("setup.py")
for req in dist.install_requires:
    print(req)
```

As a shell command that might look like:

```
python -c 'import distutils.core; print(*distutils.core.run_setup("setup.py").install_requires, sep="\n")'
```

It is also possible to use the CLI to generate egg-info and then read deps from that:

```
python setup.py egg_info
cat myproject.egg-info/requires.txt
```

However, distutils is deprecated and setuptools is trying to be a library only, so using `setup.py` in this way is quite neglected.

You might consider moving to declarative dependencies specified in `pyproject.toml` and then just reading the requirements directly with a simple TOML parser.